# Jquery Alert appearing twice in focusout

Tags: javascript, jquery

so i have this jquery:

```
    $("#dynamic_admin_edit_event_time").on("focusout", ".jamAkhir", function() {
      var $row = $(this).closest("tr");    // Find the row
      var row_time_id_edit = $row.find(".row_time_id_edit").text();
      var jam_awal = $row.find(".jamMulai").val();
      var jam_akhir = $row.find(".jamAkhir").val();

      if(jam_awal >= jam_akhir && jam_akhir !== '') {
        $("#edit_jam_akhir_"+ row_time_id_edit).css("border-color", "red");
        alert("Jam akhir event tidak boleh lebih dahulu dari jam mulai event");
        $(this).addClass('error');
        //$(".edit_event").prop("disabled",true);
      }

      else if(jam_akhir === ''){

      }

      else if(jam_awal < jam_akhir){
        $("#edit_jam_mulai_"+ row_time_id_edit).css("border-color", "lightgrey");
        $("#edit_jam_akhir_"+ row_time_id_edit).css("border-color", "lightgrey");
        $(this).removeClass('error');
      }
   });
```

So what this does is that whenever a text input with the class .jamakhir is filled, it would check with the class .jamAwal in the same row, the checking works fine and is correct, but the problem is that the alert message that shows the mistake (if the value on .jamAwal is bigger than in .jamAkhir) appeared twice, even though i only put 1 alert on the if statement, how do i make it so that it only appear once?

EDIT: HTML code for this jquery:

```
       $get_date = "SELECT tgl_event, Jam_Mulai_event, jam_akhir_event, id_jadwal_acara
                 FROM jadwal_acara
                 WHERE id_event = '$id_event'
                 AND status = '$one'";

    $result_get_date = mysqli_query($db, $get_date);
    $count_date = 1;
    while($show_date = mysqli_fetch_array($result_get_date)) {

        $tgl_event = $show_date['tgl_event'];
        $jam_mulai_event = $show_date['Jam_Mulai_event'];
        $jam_akhir_event = $show_date['jam_akhir_event'];
        $id_jadwal_acara = $show_date['id_jadwal_acara'];

        if($count_date == 1) {
            $output .= '
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td><input type="text" name="admin_edit_exist_tgl_event[]" class="form-control edittglEvent" value="' .$tgl_event. '" required></td>
                                                        <td><input type="text" name="admin_edit_exist_jam_mulai_event[]" class="form-control jamMulai" id="edit_jam_mulai_'.$count_date.'"  value="' .$jam_mulai_event. '" style="border-color: lightgrey" required></td>
                                                        <td><input type="text" name="admin_edit_exist_jam_akhir_event[]" class="form-control jamAkhir" id="edit_jam_akhir_'.$count_date.'"  value="' .$jam_akhir_event. '" style="border-color: lightgrey" required></td>
                                                        <td style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="admin_edit_exist_id_jadwal_acara[]" class="form-control" value="' .$id_jadwal_acara. '" required></td>
                                                        <td><button type="submit" name="button_edit_add_event_time" id="edit_add_event_time" class="btn btn-success">Add More Event</button></td>

                                                    ';

            $plus = "<td class='row_time_id_edit' style='visibility: hidden;'>$count_date</td></tr>";
            $output .= $plus;
            $count_date++;
        }

        else if($count_date != 1){
            $output .= '
                            <tr id="edit_row_'.$count_date.'">
                            <td><input type="text" name="admin_edit_exist_tgl_event[]" class="form-control edittglEvent" value="' .$tgl_event. '" required></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="admin_edit_exist_jam_mulai_event[]" class="form-control jamMulai" id="edit_jam_mulai_'.$count_date.'" value="' .$jam_mulai_event. '" style="border-color: lightgrey" required></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="admin_edit_exist_jam_akhir_event[]" class="form-control jamAkhir" id="edit_jam_akhir_'.$count_date.'" value="' .$jam_akhir_event. '" style="border-color: lightgrey" required></td>
                            <td style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="admin_edit_exist_id_jadwal_acara[]" class="form-control" value="' .$id_jadwal_acara. '" required></td>
                            <td><button type="submit" name="button_edit_remove_exist_event_time" id="' .$count_date. '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove_exist">Remove Event</button></td>
                            <td class="row_time_id_edit" style="visibility: hidden;">'.$count_date.'</td></tr>
                            </tr>
            ';

            $count_date++;
        }

        else{
            echo"Something Went Wrong";
        }
    }
```

There is no problem with checking the time, the problem is that the alert appeared twice, but the checking is not wrong.

Comment: That looks fine - you haven't maybe included this code twice?

Comment: No, i only put it once

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of event bubbling, try 'blur' instead of 'focusout'. If it's still not work share your HTML code

Comment: Changed to blur, and it still doesn't work sry. Give me a moment, i'd copy the html code to the question above.

EDIT: I've added the html to the code snippet in my question